# What new cross-browser features can we use if we drop support for IE6?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

My company is dropping support of IE6 and I just realize that we can use a set of great features.
Is there a list of CSS, Javascript features which we can use with IE6 RIP?

Comment: Congratulations :D Are you guys organizing a celebration?

Comment: Yes of cause:) 18th evening we will rock EZ5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsupported in IE6 (this is not a complete list):

- child selector ( div > p )
- adjacent sibling selector ( h1 + p )
- general sibling selector ( h1 ~ p )
- chained class selectors ( .class1.class2 )
- attribute selector ( a[href] )
- descendant selector after :hover pseudo-class ( div:hover span )
- chained pseudo-classes ( a:first-child:hover )
- :hover on non-anchor elements
- :first-child
- "virtual dimensions" (dimensions determined by top, right, left, bottom when position: absolute )
- min-height, min-width
- max-height, max-width
- transparent border color
- position: fixed
- background-attachment: fixed works only on the root element

Answer (score 11):

I find [When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/) to be a good resource for knowing what is available depending on what browser ranges I wish to support.

Answer (score 8):

Lots of IE6 bugs/behaviours are still prevalent in IE7. Some bugs that were fixed:

- basic alpha-transparent png support
- css child selector
- !important more properly works
- :first-letter support
- min-height
- partial click bug
- window.XMLHttpRequest became present, instead of ActiveXObject
- `abbr` tag is recognized
- `select` z-index bug is resolved as it's become window-less

Some more listed @:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649487(VS.85).aspx

There really aren't any new features. IE7 is basically what IE6 should've been, and IE8 IE7, and so forth. The only version worth truly getting excited is IE9, which has a huge amount of modern spec support compared to the prior versions.

Comment: +1: (OPINION ALERT!) IE7 was a great improvement over IE6 in so many ways (native XMLHttpRequest and various bugs, primarily), but I think 8 and then 9 are also great improvements over 7. Will we be lamenting those (needlessly, in this case) sticking with IE7 in the years to come? ;)

Comment: Another opinion alert: IE8 is the new IE6. It's CSS3 support is so limited that you still have to do a bunch of extra coding to do something that can easily be done with CSS3. IE9 shows great promise though.

Comment: @Gert "IE8 is the new IE6" -  Yea, that is pretty obvious to everyone :) I came up with that exact phrase earlier this year.

Comment: @Šime - I'm glad you feel confident enough to speak for every Web developer in the world.

Comment: Unfortunately, until IE changes to automatic updates like the other browsers, every new version of IE is the new IE6.

Answer (score 0):

What i'm most excited to be able to use, or a few things that since I can't use really make me twitchy at the css (and sometimes js) compromises which are required (in order):

1. child selector (tag > tag, no more reseting UL/LI styles!)
2. class chaining (class1.class2, less js/css!)
3. first-child (no more class="last" or first!)
4. :hover on non-anchors (what up web apps!)

Luck you!

Answer (score -1):

If you're already using jQuery you could always consult this function to see if you should use a feature ;)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/